# jquery click() not working on galleriffic page navigation

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

Please help making click() handler work.

```
  <ul class="thumbs" id="main_navi">
    <li class="cir" id="navi0"><a class="thumb" title="1st Tee" rel="history"><img src="t/1st-Tee.jpg" alt="1st Tee" /></a></li>
  </ul>

  <a id="page-nav" title="Prev" href="#1">Prev</a>

   /* this click works */
    $("#main_navi li").click(function(){
        // stop the running galleries
        $(".nivoSlider").data('nivoslider').stop();
        // Play the nivo slider from the first image of the gallery after clicking on the thumb
        $("#slider"+($(this).prevAll().length+1) + " a.nivo-control").first().click();
    });
    /* this one does not */
    $("#page-nav").click(function (){
        $(".nivoSlider").data('nivoslider').stop();
    });
```

I'm using a custom script with an auto start where thumbs highlight.  For every thumb highlighted, the big image shows up over on the right.  If I click a thumb [ $("main_navi li") ] stops the highlight.  If I click the page nav to go to page #2 however, the thumb highlight does not stop and jumps me back to page #1.

Essentially, if I go to page #2, I need the thumb highlight to stop so that I can stay on page #2.

Comment: Some of your HTML may help, or even a JS Fiddle

Comment: Are you saying that the `click()` isn't firing, or that it is firing but isn't doing what you want it to do?

Comment: I placed an alert() inside of the click(), and got none, so I'm guessing it's not firing.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** With some HTML, things are bit clear but still not very clear. as far as the page jump problem is concerned, you can fix that in 2 ways:

Add `javascript:void(0);` to href instead of the anchor tag.

```
<a id="page-nav" title="Prev" href="javascript:void(0);">Prev</a>
```

Or `return false` from click handler:

```
    $("#page-nav").live('click', (function (){
        $(".nivoSlider").data('nivoslider').stop();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that breaks the script.  I'm guessing it interferes with galleriffic's code somehow.  The HTML code for page-nav is added by galleriffic's script.

Comment: See my update. I still don't see the full picture but hopefully this will address part of the problem. Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: I have posted the script here: http://silverica.com/gallery/index.htm  As you will note, the thumbs "highlight" and go to next automatically. If you go to page two by clicking "2" or "Next" while the thumbs are highlighting on page 1, the gallery will jump back to page 1.  I need to prevent that from happening.